# CentOS guest in Debian guest on Windows 7 host: "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)"

Tags: vagrant, debian, virtualbox, virtualization

I have VirtualBox 5.1 installed on Windows 7.
There I have a guest OS Debian (64-bit) set up.
For this guest system I have both "*Enable VT-x/AMD-V*" and "*Enable Nested Paging*" boxes checked in the "*System - Accelaration*" menu and the "*Paravirtualization Interface*" is set to "*KVM*".

Now I am trying to deploy a CentOS (guest) system (following [these](https://github.com/apache/incubator-metron/tree/master/metron-deployment/vagrant/full-dev-platform) instructions to install an Apache Metron dev environment) inside the Debian guest OS, using VirtualBox 5.0 as a *provider* to *Vagrant*.

I run:

```
vagrant up
```

and receive the following output:

```
ytsboe@debian-metron ~/incubator-metron/metron-deployment/vagrant/full-dev-platform$ vagrant up
 Running with ansible-skip-tags: ["solr", "yaf"]
 Bringing machine 'node1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
 ==> node1: Box 'bento/centos-6.7' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
     node1: Box Provider: virtualbox
         node1: Box Version: >= 0
     ==> node1: Loading metadata for box 'bento/centos-6.7'
         node1: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/centos-6.7
         ==> node1: Adding box 'bento/centos-6.7' (v2.2.7) for provider: virtualbox
             node1: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/centos-6.7/versions/2.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box
         ==> node1: Successfully added box 'bento/centos-6.7' (v2.2.7) for 'virtualbox'!
         ==> node1: Importing base box 'bento/centos-6.7'...
         ==> node1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
         ==> node1: Checking if box 'bento/centos-6.7' is up to date...
         ==> node1: Setting the name of the VM: full-dev-platform_node1_1483547498018_38251
         ==> node1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
         ==> node1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
             node1: Adapter 1: nat
                 node1: Adapter 2: hostonly
             ==> node1: Forwarding ports...
                 node1: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
                 ==> node1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
                 ==> node1: Booting VM...
                 There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
                 for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "34769275-58df-4c89-af8d-d1cb3e538dc9", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Note: Many posts here suggest to turn off Hyper-V. I actually tried to do that on my Dell, but could not find it in the BIOS. Neither do I think that it would help, since the problem is in the *guest* of the *guest* ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that VirtualBox inside VirtualBox is not supported (yet): https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032