# VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX) when vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am hitting error above. I am running windows 7 and virtual box version 5.2.22

vtx is enabled as the picture shown below. I have checked from the bios and it's has enabled.

[image]

[image]

[image]

i have click the option when i run virtual box too
[image]

Somehow i still hitting the error when i run vagrant up

refer to the VMware below, the VTX is enable running on the same windows but this is not the case for virtual box.
[image]

Base on the link below, it shows that that is the limitation of virtual box. Not sure anyone has workaround or solve this issue
[CentOS guest in Debian guest on Windows 7 host: "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470247/centos-guest-in-debian-guest-on-windows-7-host-vt-x-is-not-available-verr-vmx)

Answer (score 0):

You might have Hyper-V enabled. It is usually needed for the Docker. Try disabling it via Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Hyper - V. Windows restart is required.

[image]